# Product dimensions filter by taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

**Introduction**

I am working on my own product filter based on a taxonomy called `shop-filter`. This taxonomy is meant to create filters like: "width" and "height", but also "dooropener" and "hinge type" for example.

I have multiple "small shops" which I categorize by another taxonomy called `shop-product`. So for example: "showerdoor", "showerwall", "table top" (glass products).

So the base url for a "small shop" is:

`www.website.com/shop-category/showerdoor/`

> Uses the `shop-category` taxonomy.

When you are filtering you get something like:

```
www.website.com/shop-category/showerdoor/?width=200-cm
```

> Uses the `shop-filter` terms as $_GET parameters in the url to query
>   the right results.

**The problem**

The problem is that when I want to create a 200 cm term for the parent terms "width" and "height", I get the following slugs:

```
www.website.com/shop-category/showerdoor/?height=200-cm&width=200-cm-width
```

So as you can see, I cannot have 2 terms with the same slug under 2 different parent terms.

[image]

**Showing the filters on the page**

```
<?php
// Get shop category from query var
$shop_category = get_query_var( 'shop-category' );

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'shop',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'tax_query' => array(
      array(
         'taxonomy'  => 'shop-category',
         'field'     => 'slug',
         'terms'     => $shop_category
      )
   )
);
$products = get_posts( $args );

$array = [];

foreach ( $products as $product ) {

   // Get post's terms
   if ( $filters = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'shop-filter' ) ) {

      foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {

         // If is child term
         if ( 0 != $filter->parent ) {

            // Parent does not exists yet or child does not aleady exists
            if ( empty( $array[$filter->parent] ) || ! in_array( $filter->term_id, $array[$filter->parent] ) ) {

               // Add term child under parent child in array
               $array[$filter->parent][] = $filter->term_id;
            }

         }
      }
   }
}
?>

<nav class="side-navigation filter">

   <?php
   foreach ( $array as $filter_parent_id => $filter_childs_ids ) {

      // Get parent term object
      $parent_object = get_term( $filter_parent_id, 'shop-filter' );
      ?>

      <div class="nav-part">

         <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $parent_object->name; ?></h2>
         <ul class="list">

            <?php
            foreach ( $filter_childs_ids as $filter_child_id ) {

               // Get child term object
               $child_object = get_term( $filter_child_id, 'shop-filter' );

               // For creating the item url
               $site_url   = site_url( '/shop-category/' . $shop_category );
               $query_arg  = array( $parent_object->slug => $child_object->slug );

               // Create url
               if ( ! empty( $_GET[$parent_object->slug] ) && $child_object->slug == $_GET[$parent_object->slug] ) {
                  $url = remove_query_arg( $parent_object->slug );
               }
               else if ( ! empty( $_GET ) ) {
                  $url = add_query_arg( array_merge( $_GET, $query_arg ), $site_url );
               }
               else {
                  $url = add_query_arg( $query_arg, $site_url );
               }

               $classes = [];
               if ( ! empty( $_GET[$parent_object->slug] ) && $child_object->slug == $_GET[$parent_object->slug] ) {
                  $classes[] = 'current';
               }

               echo '<li class="' . implode( ' ', $classes ) . '"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $child_object->name . '</a></li>';

            }
            ?>

         </ul>
      </div>

   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You won't be able to have two terms with the same slug in the same taxonomy. In your case, I think you will find it better to create a taxonomy for each filter (`tax_width`, `tax_height`, `tax_doorhandle`). The parent/child structure you have in the filters probably doesn't match the kinds of queries you want to make anyway (for instance, you'd never want to retrieve all products with a `height`).

Comment: @NateWr But what if I have 10 different kind of filters. Then I need to make 10 taxonomies..

Comment: Exactly. That strikes me as the best data structure for your needs.

Comment: @NateWr Alright I am gonna try!